# Prevent triggering ValueChanged when listener is attached with Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to that the event `ValueChanged` will NOT trigger once when the listener is attached?

Attaching listener:

```
  FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .GetReference("Leaders")
    .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged; //Triggers HandleValueChanged
```

The Listener:

```
void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Remove the listener if you don't want it to trigger.  You added it with `+=`, remove the same instance with `-=`
2. Put a conditional inside the trigger that determines when it should not trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I can do triggers (Option 2), the thing is that i have multiple listeners which means i need to start managing the triggers, which is something i am trying to prevent. Hoped there is a more generic way.